# How do I check the Bluez version?

Tags: bluetooth

I am using 12.04 on my machine. I want to check which version of Bluez right now my machine using. How to check that.

Answer (score 37):

BlueZ has a daemon process named 'bluetoothd'
Issue command: `bluetoothd -v` to get the active or working version of BlueZ.

Answer (score 18):

Open a terminal and enter

```
dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
```

or the slightly more obscure

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Version}\n' bluez
```

Answer (score 3):

You could go to the Software Center, search for “BlueZ” and click on the first entry. The version number is given below the description.

As for reference, on Ubuntu 13.04, I have bluez 4.101-0ubuntu8b1.